# Send Outlook mail via javascript

Tags: javascript, email, batch-file, outlook

The title may not be 100% on point.

At the place where I work, we have to send mails sometimes, to certain adresses (there are 5 of them).

Anyway, I created a batch script that lets you enter some details of the mail you have to send then the batch script executes a:

```
outlook.exe /c ipm.note /m "mail@address.com&cc=mail@address2.com&subject=SUBJECT&body=BODY"
```

This opens a new mail Outlook window as some of you may know already.

The "problem" (because it's not really a big problem) is that I have to add my signature manually because there is no switch for Outlook to do that.

Now, I got my hand on a .js script (from a simple html page, with a css, done by someone for the exact same reason, that being to just input some details about the mail, etc) that opens a new mail Outlook window by using something like:

```
window.location = 'mailto:imcc_bucuresti@telekom.ro?cc=EVI-OPS-Techproject-TLs@evalueinternational.ro&subject=[ROG URGENTARE] ' + nrbonimcc + ' Jud.' + catreimccmare ;
```

Now, how can I make the batch script call a .js script to send a "mailto" command.

The batch script is something like this:

```
@echo off

title=MAIL TOOL

set mail1=mail1@address.com
set mail2=mail2@address.com
set mail3=mail3@address.com
set mail4=mail4@address.com
set mail5=mail5@address.com



:start
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo     MAIL TOOL
echo.
echo.
echo.
set /p zone=Enter a zone: 
if '%zone%'=='a' goto zone1
if '%zone%'=='b' goto zone1
if '%zone%'=='c' goto zone2
if '%zone%'=='d' goto zone2
etc



:zone1
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo     MAIL TOOL
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo     SENDING MAIL TO ZONE 1
echo.
echo.
echo.
outlook.exe /c ipm.note /m "%mail1%&cc=%workmail%&subject=ZONE 1 MAIL (%zone%)&body=ZONE 1 BODY TEXT"
echo.
echo     COMMAND EXECUTED SUCCESSFULLY, PRESS ANY KEY TO CONTINUE.
echo.
pause>NUL
goto start


:zone2
etc.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're actually trying to open a `mailto:` URL, not run JS code.

You can open an arbitrary URL from a batch file using `start url`.

Comment: I don't know why but this command (start iexplore.exe "mailto:etc") opens a new mail Outlook window but with no signature, just like the batch script.

Comment: Ok, I modified the .js script to add some text in the body (it only added text in the subject field) and it adds the text but with no signature like the batch script...